# Unable to run Gerrit on Docker in a Synology NAS

Tags: docker, gerrit, synology

I am trying to install and run Gerrit on Docker hosted in a Synology NAS. I have downloaded the latest image of Gerrit from "gerritcodereview" and I have the ports setup as the following.

```
29418:29418 
8080:8080
```

When I start the container, it runs for about 2-3 minutes and then stops automatically. While it's running, I don't see any webpage loading at :8080. The webpage shows "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". Finally I find the following error looking at the Gerrit docker container logs. Any idea how to fix this and have Gerrit running?

```
No SSH keys under /var/gerrit/etc
while locating com.google.gerrit.sshd.HostKeyProvider
at com.google.gerrit.sshd.SshHostKeyModule.configure(SshHostKeyModule.java:25)
while locating org.apache.sshd.common.keyprovider.KeyPairProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Gerrit needs to be initialised, as per:
https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/docker-gerrit#initialize-gerrit-db-and-git-repositories-with-docker

Basically you need to force the init command while starting the container, so that it generates the ssh key.

If using the docker compose, add `command: init` (the line is already commented out in the official compose file https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/docker-gerrit#using-gerrit-in-production).